# R grepl returns different result

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to check whether a string follows a specific pattern. The string must follow the pattern [check(id("numeric only"),"1 of the specified keywords")], where specified keywords = D, D5, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, W6, W0, M, Q1, Q2, Q3, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, Y1, Y2, A2, Y4, Y5, A3, Y7, Y8, A4, YA, YB, A1.

```
freq <- c("D", "D5", "W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W0", "M", "Q1", 
           "Q2", "Q3", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "Y1", "Y2", "A2", 
           "Y4", "Y5", "A3", "Y7", "Y8", "A4", "YA", "YB", "A1")
> grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241w),A1)")
[1] FALSE

> grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241),A1)")
[1] TRUE

> grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\b", paste0(freq, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241w),A1)")
[1] FALSE

> grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\b", paste0(freq, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241),A1)")
[1] FALSE
```

The first, second and third output is the correct result, however I am expecting the fourth result is a TRUE but instead R return a FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Second line from you
grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241),A1)")
#TRUE

#Change A1 to A2
grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "check(id(32131241),A2)")
#FALSE

#Adding surrounding <>
grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "<check(id(32131241),A2)>")
#FALSE

#Adding perl=TRUE
grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b\\)\\>", "<check(id(32131241),A2)>", perl=TRUE)
#TRUE

#Add () arround |
grepl("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),(\\bA1\\b|\\bA2\\b)\\)\\>", "<check(id(32131241),A2)>", perl=TRUE)
#TRUE

#Here you have to add one additional paste
grepl(paste0("\\<check\\(id\\(+\\d+\\),(\\b", paste0(freq, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)\\)\\>"), "<check(id(32131241),A1)>", perl=TRUE)
#TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the final code works like a charm!!